# How to make changes in keyboard shortcuts permanent?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, plasma

I want to change <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> keyboard shortcut that invokes start menu on **KDE Plasma**, because it interferes with the Far Commander I am using. **System Settings** > **Shortcuts** can do that. There are some peculiar influences on how the Windows key alone works, to disable it, I must create the new shortcut as "Global Alternate", not simply "Global". After I press "Apply", the new alternate shortcut comes in force and the old one stops interfering with other programs:

[image: Global Keyboard Shortcuts]

However, the setting resets to default after each reboot. I can export my shortcuts to a file, but that does not help. Other shortcuts like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to activate Firefox remain permanent after reboot, but the one for application launcher widget does not. How can I make it permanent?